# Auto-completing Empty input in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete field setup as:

```
<auto-complete source="vm.groupList" min-length="0" max-results-to-show="10" 
highlight-matched-text="true" select-first-match="false">
</auto-complete>
```

This works fine. I further want to add that when I enter nothing into my search field, all the options should be displayed. In the current scenario, if nothing is entered, there are no autocomplete suggestions.

Edit:

In ng-tags-imput.js, it's implementation being something like this:

```
tagsInputConfig.load('autoComplete', $scope, $attrs, {
                template: [String, 'ngTagsInput/auto-complete-match.html'],
                debounceDelay: [Number, 100],
                minLength: [Number, 3],
                highlightMatchedText: [Boolean, true],
                maxResultsToShow: [Number, 10],
                loadOnDownArrow: [Boolean, false],
                loadOnEmpty: [Boolean, false],
                loadOnFocus: [Boolean, false],
                selectFirstMatch: [Boolean, true],
                displayProperty: [String, '']
            });
```

On changing the loadOnDownArrow, loadOnEmpty and loadOnFocus to True, I was able to achieve the empty autocomplete.

Comment: Try [md-autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete). It has this feature

Comment: Can't use md-autocomplete due to project dependencies constraint. Is there a workaround for the normal autocomplete for the same?

Comment: Could you please share the link to normal autocomplete directive?